# Best way to update the content of large lookups tables

Tags: postgresql, transaction, postgresql-9.3, import

In our application we have a about 20 tables that contain lookup information (read only data that the application doesn't modify).

Nightly we'd like to update this information by deleting all the content and running a script that run a series of inserts and updates. This script could be a couple of million lines long.

I was thinking to run this within a transaction.

What behaviour should I expect from the database? Will the tables be updated at the end of the transaction without downtime?

Is there something I should be aware of when running large transactions?

The database I'm using is Postgres 9.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the script contains *only* `INSERT`s, `UPDATE`s and `DELETE`s to the target table(s), and that the app never attempts row locks (`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE/SHARE`) or DML on those tables, then the script shouldn't affect the app except for the increased load on the DB server.

When the script commits, the changes will instantly become visible to new statements (if the transaction is in `READ COMMITTED` isolation) or transactions (if they're in `SERIALIZABLE` isolation).

However...

> Nightly we'd like to update this information by deleting all the content and running a script that run a series of inserts and updates. This script could be a couple of million lines long.

You should use `COPY` for this instead of a script full of inserts and updates, if possible.

Just:

- DELETE FROM mytable;
- VACUUM mytable;
- COPY mytable FROM 'inputfile.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV)

or similar.

It will be a *lot* faster. Because of the next point, you might want to load several smaller files though.

> Is there something I should be aware of when running large transactions?

Long running data modifying transactions prevent `VACUUM` from cleaning up rows in other tables that they might be able to "see". This can create quite a lot of table bloat.

If you use `READ COMMITTED` isolation and stick to individual statements that don't take an extremely long time you won't have a problem, because the snapshot that controls which rows the transaction can see gets updated after each statement.

It's mostly a concern if you're using cursors, working in `SERIALIZABLE` isolation, or running extremely long-running individual data modifying statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a foreign key constraint from the data table that points to any of these 20 tables you will not be able to bulk delete from them.

Obviously the application will not receive any results if it tries to read any of the lookup tables after the deletion and before the insertion of the new values.  Will the application crash if this happens?

Deleting and loading millions of rows will blow out the size of your transaction files.  Ensure you have enough disk space to handle this and appropriate log maintenance procedures in place.

I would like to suggest a better architecture to you.  Load the new data into a set of staging tables.  There will be a staging table for each lookup table, with the same columns and data types.  Run verification against these staging tables, if required.  Perform and "upsert" (aka Merge) from each staging table to its corresponding lookup table.  Perform this in batches of a few thousand rows at a time, with an explicit transaction.  The ideal batch size will depend on your system and requirements.  This will afford good restart capabilities in the case of an error and may limit log file growth, depending on your setup.  Once complete, truncate the staging tables ready for the next run.